# Run powershell script for each folder with subfolders

Tags: powershell

I have a few scripts that I need to run against a dozen folders all with a relative path. I'm trying to solve this with a master script to run for each folder in that path, one folder at a time. The folders are all children of the "here" folder in the below path. I can't seem to get the syntax right, but I think I'm close :)

Is there a more efficient way to run a script against the contents of every folder in a directory, one folder at a time?

```
$pdfFolder = 'C:\path\to\folders\here'
$Completed = Get-ChildItem $pdfFolder -Recurse

ForEach-Object ($Completed){
Invoke-Expression -Command "C:\path\where\scriptis\script.ps1"
}`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$pdfFolder = 'C:\path\to\folders\here'

# Get all subfolders - note the -Directory switch (PSv3+)
$Completed = Get-ChildItem $pdfFolder -Recurse -Directory

# Pipe the subfolders to ForEach-Object, invoke the
# script with & (avoid Invoke-Expression), and pass the subfolder
# at hand as an argument.
$Completed | ForEach-Object {
  & "C:\path\where\scriptis\script.ps1" $_
}
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `Get-ChildItem $pdfFolder -Recurse`

This command returns not just folders (directories), but also *files*. To limit the output to folders, pass switch `-Directory` (PSv3+).

---

> `ForEach-Object ($Completed) { ... }`

You're confusing the syntax of the [`foreach` *loop*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach) with the syntax of the pipeline-based [`ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object).
The cmdlet expects input from the *pipeline*, so you must use 
`$Completed | ForEach-Object { ... }` instead.

Also note that unless you truly need to collect all subfolders in an array first, you can simply pipe your `Get-ChildItem` call directly to `ForEach-Object`.

---

> `Invoke-Expression -Command "C:\path\where\scriptis\script.ps1"`

[`Invoke-Expression` should be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/), because it is rarely the right tool and can be a security risk.

All you need to invoke a script by its *quoted* and/or stored-in-a-*variable* file path is to use [`&`, the call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-), as shown above.